# Signing Authoritative Zones bind9 ubuntu server

Tags: server, bind

I'm trying to run dnssec, sign authoritative zones in bind9, but I've seen many different versions of doing this and I'm lost.

My named.conf:

```
// This is the primary configuration file for the BIND DNS server named.
//
// Please read /usr/share/doc/bind9/README.Debian for information on the
// structure of BIND configuration files in Debian, *BEFORE* you customize
// this configuration file.
//
// If you are just adding zones, please do that in /etc/bind/named.conf.local

include "/etc/bind/named.conf.options";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.local";
include "/etc/bind/named.conf.default-zones";
include "/etc/bind/rndc.key";

controls {
     inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { "rndc-key"; };
};

logging { 
     channel bind_log {
         file "/var/log/named/bind_log";
         print-severity yes;
         print-time yes;
         severity info;
    };
    category default { bind_log; };
};

dnssec-policy "custom" {
        dnskey-ttl 600;
        keys {
            ksk lifetime P1Y algorithm ecdsap384sha384;
            zsk lifetime 60d algorithm ecdsap384sha384;
 };
        nsec3param iterations 0 optout no salt-length 0;
 };
```

My named.conf.default-zones:

```
zone "ns1.ubuntuserver" in {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.ns1";
    allow-transfer { none; };
    key-directory "/etc/bind/keys/first.com";
    inline-signing yes;
    dnssec-policy custom;
    parental-agents { 192.168.1.16; };
```

};

I checked named-checkconf, everything is correct, but what's next, I know it's something related to keyrollover, but I don't know how to go about it.

These are the links I used:

https://kb.isc.org/docs/dnssec-key-and-signing-policy#wait-for-rollovers-to-complete
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-dnssec-on-an-authoritative-bind-dns-server-2
https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.21/dnssec-guide.html

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 23.10
Release:    23.10
Codename:   mantic